# CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation not found

Tags: ios4, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have been trying to add a feature to my app to get the location and put the variables into a mysql db. I've added CoreLocation.framework and imported `<CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>` in the headers. I've tried different code but i always come up with similar errors such as the ones commented below. Is it possible that the framework isn't linked right?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:   (NSDictionary *)launchOptions                              
{ 
 CLLocationManager = self; // Expected identifier or '('
 [self startUpdatingLocation:nil]; // instance method '-startUpdatingLocation' not found
}



-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
 CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] release];
//initializing 'CLLocationManager *' with an expression of incompatible type 'void'
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation:nil];
//do stuff with the coordinates
}



@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the corrections of your code. It should work. After that your code should implement CLLocationManagerDelegate methods to get the location info.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:   (NSDictionary *)launchOptions                              
{ 
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
 locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation:nil];}



-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

 CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
 locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation:nil];

//do stuff with the coordinates
}
```